# How to handle page level pure javascript in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First time using react and am converting a poc. Have a bunch of pure javascript, mostly code for animations on a canvas (almost game level). Each page has too much code to load it all in the base html file.

I'm sure there is something I'm missing in my searches, but I'm not sure the correct way to handle including it with each individual page.

I tried just putting it inline like this, but it doesn't like some of the code, so I'm assuming it's not the best way.

```
componentDidMount() { <script>....</script> }
```

Found an example doing

```
componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "file.js";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
```

No matter how I path it, it just loads up the index page. So unexpected error < because it starts with < html>

Not sure it matters, but my JS includes a number of functions, var declarations, addEventListener and an onload.

Comment: why do you want to include scripts this way? Usually the best approach is to export the wanted functionality in your external script and import the relevant functions / objects inside your react component

Comment: It always loads in your index page because that's technically the only page you have in React since React is a single-page application library...

Comment: @messerbill Sorry, new to react. Not sure what you mean by export the wanted functionality. Don't need details, but a basic example link would be great.

Comment: @Baruch loading a meg+ of code is not a reasonable answer when less than a 100k is needed.

Comment: for example you have a date-picker or something else defined in an external script and you export it like `export class MyDatePicker { ..... ` and you want to make use of it inside another component you can import it using `import { MyDatePicker } from './path/to/datepicker/MyDatePicker`

Comment: If I'm just exporting a single function, how would I handle global vars? Eg: pInfo = { startPos: 0, endPos: 400} function a() { pInfo.startPos } function b() { pInfo.StartPos++ }

Comment: global vars are mostly an anti-pattern. I would create kind of a config file containing those default values and pass them as parameter to the imported function

Comment: Agreed with anti-pattern. Thinking of something like a game which this basically is, health would be global unless I'm missing a better way (sorry never built anything web based like this before). The config file would still be JS? How would it be included or would those var's be in the react code?

Comment: you can either take a config file (such as .js or .json) or you can load your default data out off a database

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for **import**.

```
import scriptFromGame from './script.js'

const App = ()=> {
// code reuse from script.js
//let's assume points

const {points} = scriptFromGame;

return <div> {points} </div>

}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that way. It didn't seem to run the addEventListener or onload functions. Was that my mistake somehow?

Comment: You have to bind it to react.